# best practice for imaging a flex 4.5 mobile window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, background, flex4.5

I want to design a login window in flex 4.5 for mobile. (very new in flex)
what is the best way to BackGround image the window? 
is there any sample?

Answer (score 0):

check out this post:
http://spy6.blogspot.com/2011/07/adding-background-to-mobile-flex-45.html